# Git for development and live websites

Tags: git, performance, git-cherry-pick

I'm using Git for both my development and live websites, and keep each in their own branches 'dev' and 'master'. When I finish testing on the 'dev' branch I merge my changes back to 'master', however there are several files which I need to keep specific to just the 'dev' branch / server.

I.e. index.php have a 'development server' message shown at top of all pages, and no Google Analytics tracking, and I want to keep it this way.

Also some config files which should not change when I merge.

I have been using cherry-pick, but this is slow and frustrating... is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to setup [.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) files in your repo.

Basically your config files should not be added to your repo.  You can use a `.gitignore` file 
to do this.

Say if you have an `includes/` directory. In there make a `.gitignore` file with the following in it:

```
config.php
```

This says that `config.php` from this directory should not be added to the repo.  Note: this will not work if the file has already been added.  If it has already been added then you must [git rm](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) the file.

Now since the `config.php` file won't exist in your repo at all, I would recommend creating a `config.sample.php` which looks exactly like you `config.php` file and is part of your repo.  This way when you clone (or someone else clones) your project they know exactly what should be in the config file.

Comment: As for the index dev message (which really shouldn't be necessary) and Analytics you could include them in the header/footer as separate files.  Then do the same as with the config above (don't store in repo, create sample version (which are part of repo) and you're good.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping to avoid using .gitignore, which I do already for other files, but can see now that its probably the way to go.

Comment: ..and for Google Analytics code, I'll just put that in as a setup var in my config file! Thanks guys!